# Remove from list comparing elements using java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to use java8 streams to remove items from a list based elements of the object and confused on implementation. I have an object with startdate,enddate and id and I want to compare objects with other objects in the list by checking if the startdate and enddate are eqaul then remove the object which has the least ids.

```
startdate    enddate      Id
 ---------   ---------   ----- 
 01-01-2018  01-05-2018   1
 01-01-2018  01-05-2018   2
 01-01-2018  01-05-2018   3
 01-20-2018  01-25-2018   4
 01-20-2018  01-25-2018   5
```

Then the resulting list will be

```
 startdate    enddate      Id
 ---------   ---------   -----      
 01-01-2018  01-05-2018   3    
 01-20-2018  01-25-2018   5
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: lets not downvote immediately..
@arjun: can you please update what have you tried and what is not working

Comment: Have you tried using a stream filter yet?

Answer (score -1):

If your objects have properties like (int id, Date startDate, Date endDate), you can group by them using some container class like Pair from Apache Commons, then find max id on grouped lists:

```
originalObjectsList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(t -> new Pair(t.startDate, t.endDate)))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .map(t -> t.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.id)).get())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Pair is abstract and cannot be instantiated?

Comment: No. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html - you can create your own container object with equals/hashcode for grouping

Comment: It is mentioned Pair as abstract in the doc. Implementations include mutable and immutable. I am trying Immutable to see how it works!